# How to get index of regex match of only the matched and included part?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

```
txt =  'Port of Discharge/ Airport of destination\tXYZABC\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t44B'
```

I am doing:

```
reg_ind = [(m.start(0),m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(r' port.{0,6}discharge.{0,3}/.{0,3}airport.{0,7}destination.*(?=44B)', txt,re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)]

print(reg_ind)
[(0, 56)]

print(txt[reg_ind[0][0]: reg_ind[0][1]])
Port of Discharge/ Airport of destination       XYZABC
```

I want the index to end at Airport of destination.

Desired output:

```
print(reg_ind)
[(0, 41)]

print(txt[reg_ind[0][0]: reg_ind[0][1]])
Port of Discharge/ Airport of destination
```

Comment: Did my solution help? Please let know if you need more help.

Comment: Yes Wiktor, it helped for the question I asked. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59981596/3832970)  and upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may move `.*` into the lookahead to avoid consuming that part of the match:

```
port.{0,6}discharge.{0,3}/.{0,3}airport.{0,7}destination(?=.*44B)
                                                         ^^^^^^^^
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yTwY57/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2d7jl9):

```
import re

txt =  'Port of Discharge/ Airport of destination\tXYZABC\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t44B'
pat = r' port.{0,6}discharge.{0,3}/.{0,3}airport.{0,7}destination(?=.*44B)'
reg_ind = [(m.start(0),m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(pat, txt,re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)]
print(reg_ind) # => [(0, 41)]
```